# submit a form with post based on conditions in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have the following form in my forms.py :

```
class PaymentMethodForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentMethodForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        payment_choices = ['online payment', 'payment at delivery']
        self.payment_method_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=payment_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

now this is the page in an online shop where you select your payment method. as you see, we have two methods, one is payment at delivery time which means there should not be any payments in the website, and the other one is online payment. In the case of the user choosing online payment, I should submit a form via post that looks something like this and after that redirect the user to the action url :

```
<form id="Form2" method="post" Action="https://somepaymentsite.com/gateway.aspx"
>
<input type="hidden" name="invoiceNumber" value="<%= invoiceNumber %>"
/>
<input type="hidden" name="invoiceDate" value="<%= invoiceDate %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= amount %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="terminalCode" value="<%= terminalCode %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="merchantCode" value="<%= merchantCode %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirectAddress" value="<%= redirectAddress
%>" />
<input type="hidden" name="timeStamp" value="<%= timeStamp %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="<%= action %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="sign" value="<%= sign %>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="‫"continue‬ />
</form>
```

now what I have in mind for doing this is that instead of putting this html stuff in my template (html file) I will get the radio button choice the user has chosen and if they chose online payment, I will submit a form like the above in my views.py . the problem is, I do not know how to go about this. I googled things but I didn't find anything good on how to post a form in a view in django. Can anybody help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, "submit form from the view" is the same as do POST request to https://somepaymentsite.com/gateway.aspx with data `{'invoiceNumber': 12345, 'invoiceDate': '10.10.2015', ...}`. You can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library in this case.

```
# in view
# if online payment then
r = request.post('https://somepaymentsite.com/gateway.aspx', data=payload)
# processing r (error handling or something else)
```

where `payload` is dictionary `{'invoiceNumber': 12345, 'invoiceDate': '10.10.2015', ...}` that you construct somehow.

Comment: that is an awesome answer sir or lady! but I may have forgotten to clarify my question and i will do so now, will doing this post redirect the user also? because I need to redirect the user to the payment site also after the post.

Comment: return HttpResponseRedirect(<url here>)?

Comment: no, I want to post the data and redirect at the same time, or else im not sure that posting first and redirecting will work. so will it? and if not, can i do both at the same time?